# Why are there not 3 independent vectors which solve Ax=0, Ay=0, and Az=0 where a is a 3x3 of ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asked to find two independent vectors which solved the equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}x=0
$$
I determined that
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
y=\begin{bmatrix}5\\-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}
$$
would work since the sum of each value in them equals 0. e.g:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\cdot1+\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\cdot1+\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\cdot-2=0
$$

they are also not linear combinations of each other. However what stops me from finding a third independent variable such as:

$$
z=\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\-6\end{bmatrix}
$$

is z not independent of x and y, or am I missing something?

Comment: You get $0$ iff the vector $x$ is orthogonal to vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with all $1$'s for its components. Obvious there are two linearly independent vectors that are orthogonal to $\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\end{array}\right]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\-6\end{bmatrix}=\frac{24}7\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}-\frac27\begin{bmatrix}5\\-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}.$$So, they are *not* linearly independent. It turns out that$$\dim\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\in\Bbb R^3\,\middle|\,\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}=0\right\}=2,$$and therefore you will not be able to find three linearly independent solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your $z$ is in fact NOT independent of $x$ and $y$ because
$$\frac{24}{7}x + \frac{-2}{7}y=z$$

You can also give the following argument on why you only find two independet solutions. The rank of the matrix $A$ is $1$ (it has exactly one linear independent column) and so by the rank-nullity theorem (that states that rk$(A)$ + dim$(N(A)) = 3$ in this case) where $N(A)$ is the nullspace of $A$. Therefore the dimension of the Nullspace is 2 and there are only two linear independent vectors satisfying $Ax=0$.

Comment: the general version of the rank-nullity theorem is as follows: If $A$ is a $n \times m$-matrix then rk$(A) + $ dim$(N(A)) = m$.